# Why is the super keyword in Java not referring to the super class?

Tags: java, super

The `super` keyword in a subclass (`Savings`) is not referring to the `Account` class. I am trying to reference the total instance of the `Account` class by using `super.total`, however it is giving me the total of the `Savings` class.

`total` and `super.total` are the same. Furthermore, when I print out `super.getClass()` in the console, it gives me the subclass (`Savings`) instead of the super class (`Accounts`).

**Savings.java**

```
public class Savings extends Account {
    
    
    public Savings(int initial, User owner, double history, double monthInterest) {
        super(initial, owner);
        int total = getTotal();


        deposit(history * 12 * monthInterest / 100 * (total + 55),
                "monthly interest",
                "Total interest accumulated in " + Math.round(history * 12) + " months");

    }
    
    public void transferS(int amount) {
        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println(super.total);
    }
```

**Account.java**

```
public class Account {
    
    private User owner;
    protected int total;

    public Account(int initial, User owner) {
    
        this.total = initial;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword

Comment: There is only one total field that your `Savings` class inherits. I'm not sure why you think there should be 2 `total` fields and what you expect their values to be when you clearly only define one field.

Comment: `total` and `super.total` is the same field . Why are you expecting 2 different outputs?

Comment: While `super` can be used to access the parent class's method implementations (or even parent interfaces through `MyInterface.super.someMethod()`), the fields that are inherited are a part of the object instance you are working with (always inherited), and static fields are never inherited. There isn't an ambiguity to resolve through `super.total` (which the answer below beat me to, drat!)

Comment: More to consider:  why did you make `Account.total` `protected`?  Try changing to `private`, and compile.  Does that help clarify what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define any `total` property in your derived class (`Savings`), thus when accessing `total` you get the property defined only in the base class `Account` (there is no alternative in your implementation of `Savings`). If you need to introduce distinct properties used between base and derived classes with the same name, define a new property with the same name in the derived class, like this:

```
public class Savings extends Account {

    int total;
    ...
```

With this implementation you'll get two different variables `total` and `super.total` which store different values.

Comment: Thanks, although when I print super.getClass(), why does it give me the sub class (Savings)?

Comment: @Joshua `getClass()` gives you the actual class, which is still `Savings`. `super` is only to access implementation of a parent class (e.g. so you can access the 'original' method if you've overridden it). It doesn't magically transform a thing to the parent class.

Comment: @Joshua Consider `this` and `super` standing for the (same) object instance of which the actual class is asked in `Object.getClass()`. Just that `this` has also Savings fields added.